# Converting special charactes such as Ã¼ and Ãƒ back to their original, latin alphbet counterparts in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, special-characters, latin, mojibake

I have been given an export from a MySQL database that seems to have had it's encoding muddled somewhat over time and contains a mix of `HTML char codes` such as `& uuml;` and more problematic characters representing the same letters such as `Ã¼` and `Ãƒ`. It is my task to to bring some consistency back to the file and get everything into the correct Latin characters, e.g. `ú` and `ó`.

An example of the sort of string I am dealing with is

> DesinfektionslÃƒÂ¶sungstÃƒÂ¼cher fÃƒÂ¼r FlÃƒÂ¤chen

Which should equate to

```
50 Tattoo Desinfektionsl ö    sungst ü    cher f ü    r Fl ä    chen 
50 Tattoo Desinfektionsl ÃƒÂ¶ sungst ÃƒÂ¼ cher f ÃƒÂ¼ r Fl ÃƒÂ¤ chen
```

Is there a method available in C#/.Net 4.5 that would successfully re-encode the likes of `Ã¼` and `Ãƒ` to `UTF-8`?

Else what approach would be advisable?

Also is the paragraph character `¶` in the above example string an actual paragraph character or part of some other character combination?

I have created a lookup table in the case of needing to do find and replace which is below, however I am unsure as to how complete it is.

```
Ã‰ -> É
â€œ -> "
â€ -> "
Ã‡ -> Ç
Ãƒ -> Ã
Ã©, 'é
Ã  -> À
Ãº -> ú
â€¢ -> -
Ã˜ -> Ø
Ãµ -> õ
Ã­ -> í
Ã¢ -> â
Ã£ -> ã
Ãª -> ê
Ã¡ -> á
Ã© -> é
Ã³ -> ó
â€“ -> –
Ã§ -> ç
Âª -> ª
Âº -> º
Ã  -> à
```

Comment: Point of pedantry: `Ã¼` and `Ãƒ` are not "special characters" exactly, but **[Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)**.

Comment: @Boann ped away... interesting

Comment: Btw your post is somewhat misleading, after repairing the data I got `Desinfektionslösungstücher für Flächen`, which seems to be correct but in your expected result you have spaces.

Comment: @Esailija Yes put in the spaces, there just to illustrate what maps to what...

Comment: Useful info: In order to quickly debug this kind of issues you can use this website: https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en
For this particular example, copy/paste the string in the question, then select UTF-8 as source and WINDOWS-1252 as displayed. Then click OK. Copy/paste resulting text to upper text box again and re-run with the same settings. You will see the original string.

Comment: Anyone knows if the table is complete? I think some characters are missing

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, first of all, as the data has been decoded using the wrong encoding, it's likely that some of the characters are impossible to recover. It looks like it's UTF-8 data that incorrectly decoded using an 8-bit encoding.

There is no built in method to recover data like this, because it's not something that you normally do. There is no reliable way to decode the data, because it's already broken.

What you can try, is to encode the data, and decode it using the wrong encoding again, just the other way around:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

The `Encoding.Default` uses the current ANSI encoding for your system. You can try some different encodings there and see which one gives the best result.

Comment: Thanks, I think your theory that the data may be irrecoverable could well be correct. I have broken the string down like so... 50 
Tattoo Desinfektionsl ö    sungst ü    cher f ü    r Fl ä chen --- and  ---

50 Tattoo Desinfektionsl ÃƒÂ¶ sungst ÃƒÂ¼ cher f ÃƒÂ¼ r Fl ÃƒÂ¤ chen. so I know what should be appearing where but still cannot convert

Comment: Your code combined with the findings of @pawlakppp solved the issue so thanks to both of you.

Comment: Possibly the python 3 equivalent: `s.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf8')`

Answer (score 17):

The data is only partly unrecoverable due to Windows-1252 encoding having 5 unassigned slots. Some modifications of Windows-1252 fill these with control
characters but those don't make it to posts in Stackoverflow. If modified
Windows-1252 has been used you can fully recover as long as you don't lose
the hidden control characters in copy pastes.

There is also the non-breaking space character that is ignored or turned into a space usually with copypastes, but that's not an issue when you deal with bytes directly.

The misencoding abuse this string has gone through is:

```
UTF-8 -> Windows-1252 -> UTF-8 -> Windows-1252
```

To recover, here is an example:

```
String a = "DesinfektionslÃƒÂ¶sungstÃƒÂ¼cher fÃƒÂ¼r FlÃƒÂ¤chen";
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.GetEncoding(65001);
Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

string result = utf8.GetString(win1252.GetBytes(utf8.GetString(win1252.GetBytes(a))));

Console.WriteLine(result);
//Desinfektionslösungstücher für Flächen
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out that approach.

Comment: +1 This is good stuff. Thanks. I've been able to apply this technique using either iconv or applescript.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably windows-1252 encoded string which you read as UTF-8.

As Guffa mentioned data has been corrupted.

Lets take a look on bytes: 
ö -> C3B6 in UTF8

in windows-1252
C3 ->Ã
B6 ->¶

so ö ->Ã¶

what about all these "ƒÂ":

ƒ ->83
Â ->C2

Honesty i don't know why they appear, but you can try erase them and do some conversions as Guffa mentioned. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I am following the same lines of investigation myself and have removed "ƒÂ". A reexport of the data has removed them and turned the A-hats to A-tildes which is good, then there seems to be a clear conversion as laid out here: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a completer list:

http://bueltge.de/wp-content/download/wk/utf-8_kodierungen.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've been troubled by this char problem before.
Solution:

My .(cs)html file was UTF-8; I converted to UTF-8Y (UTF-8 with a BOM).