# Data cleaning first names and last names but they have weird structure with symbols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm trying to clean an SQL retail database however i'm confused at the structure of the first name columns so ideally i would like a clean set of names

What i had attempted was

```
 #change the datatype of first_name to str
        user_dataframe['first_name'] = user_dataframe['first_name'].astype('string')
        user_dataframe['last_name'] = user_dataframe['last_name'].astype('string')
```

Which just changed the data type from object to string but now i am not sure how to search for the strings that i do not want

the string which are dirty come in this format

```
Hans JÃ¼rgen
BÃ¤rbel
SÃ¼leyman
SÃ¶ren
Klaus-JÃ¼rgen
2GU3G97VI1
I7IJDAPMIM
GÃ¼lten
DD0K0FUDRY
```

What i am thinking if using a regex expression to drop any rows the have the following pattern character followed by number but i'm not sure what some of the symbols mean on dirty data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the encoding in Python/Pandas. Try to change the encoding, when reading the data. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
and potentially https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings.

Also see the following answer:
[Converting special charactes such as Ã¼ and Ãƒ back to their original, latin alphbet counterparts in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980200/converting-special-charactes-such-as-%C3%83%C2%BC-and-%C3%83%C6%92-back-to-their-original-latin-alp)

Comment: I know that they use utf-8 for the default encoding when reading into pandas dataframe,  does that mean the weird symbols are from reading as a utf-8 when it should've been read from sql using a different encoding

Answer (score 0):

As someone has mentioned, it is the encoding type which caused the issue, using utf-8-sig encoding fixed the issue of the weird characters